# ASP/C# How to retrieve textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, textbox

We have a web page with an asp.net textbox:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="username">Username: </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="username" Width="300px" AutoCompleteType="None" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="username" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" />
```

I also have this piece of code on the following page:

```
<% 
  String s = Request.Form["username"];
  Response.Write(s);
%>
```

But the problem is it will not print the value.
There are no error codes displayed on either page.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you go to the following page? Fields don't get automatically carried over.

Comment: Dont worry about that. the form gets submitted by a submit button.

Comment: Don't write code like that unless you are using classic ASP.

Comment: so how do i write it

Comment: @discuss In the accompanying code behind (`.aspx.cs`) file.

Comment: `discuss` asking question like `so how do i write it` really does you no good except that you get a quick answer if someone were to provide you with one .. but what have you actually gained or learned...? basically what I am saying is if you have access to [How to retrieve Textbox Value](http://www.google.com) the `Internet` then show more effort on your end

Answer (score 3):

WebForms is meant to be used a bit differently than you'd typically expect. If everything on the page is "wired up" correctly, you should be able to get at the text box value this way.

```
<script runat="server">
  void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Page.IsPostBack) {
      string s = username.Text;
      Response.Write(s);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Typically, you would do this in the Click event handler of the button you want to act as the form submit button. The above will work regardless of which button is clicked.

Comment: Try wrapping the code in a server-side script tag and catching the page load event. I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: do a google search on how to use `<% %>` in C# .net as well `discuss`

Comment: I get this error message after adding it to the source page.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'IsPostback' and no extension method 'IsPostback' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Typo, it's 'IsPostBack' with a capital "B".

Comment: Thanks Ventaur! This works when putting it on the source page. But putting it on the following page brings up "unauthorised page" after clicking the submit button. Is this intended for the login page.

Comment: In most cases, WebForms are meant to "post back" to themselves. In other words, the page submits to itself and handles that submission there before redirecting elsewhere, or remaining with errors. What do you mean by the "following page"? Are you using PostBackUrl on a Button, or some other way to get to another page?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted out my own problem. I was incorrectly using " and needed to re-organise the code.